# Writing a C++ class with message_filters member

Tags: message-filters

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have the following code:

```
#include ....

using namespace sensor_msgs;
using namespace message_filters;

std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<capygroovy::Ticks const> > ticks;
ros::Time last = ros::Time::now();

void callback(const ImageConstPtr& msg,const ImageConstPtr& msg2,const capygroovy::TicksConstPtr& msg3)
{
    ......

    ticks = ticks_cache.getInterval(last,msg3->header.stamp);

    ......
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "db_creator_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    message_filters::Subscriber<capygroovy::Ticks> ticks_sub(nh,"/ticks",1);
    message_filters::Cache<capygroovy::Ticks> ticks_cache(ticks_sub,10);

    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> rgb_sub(nh,"/camera/rgb/image_rect",1);
    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> dpt_sub(nh,"/camera/depth/image_rect_raw",1);
    typedef sync_policies::ApproximateTime<Image, Image, capygroovy::Ticks> MySyncPolicy;
    Synchronizer<MySyncPolicy> sync(MySyncPolicy(10), rgb_sub, dpt_sub, ticks_sub);
    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2, _3));
    
    ......

    return 0;
}
```

That, of course, is wrong because I declare `ticks_cache` in the main and when I call the method `getInterval()` in the callback I get the error:

> /home/dede/catkin_ws/src/db_creator/src/db_creator_node.cpp:24:
> error: ‘ticks_cache’ was not declared
> in this scope

I suppose that a nice solution would be to write a class with the message_filters as members but in order to initialize them you need to pass to their constructor the node handle and the topic names. The problem is that I really can't figure out how this could be done, so any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172772/writing-a-c++-class-with-message_filters-member/) by [schizzz8](https://answers.ros.org/users/3511/schizzz8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 183 on 2014-06-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Without adding a class (which would be best) or globals, you can pass easily an extra parameter to your callback, something like this:

```
void callback(const ImageConstPtr& msg,const ImageConstPtr& msg2,const capygroovy::TicksConstPtr& msg3,
              message_filters::Cache<capygroovy::Ticks> &ticks_cache)
{
    ......

    ticks = ticks_cache.getInterval(last,msg3->header.stamp);

    ......
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ......

    sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, _1, _2, _3, ticks_cache));

    ......

    return 0;
}
```

It really is as simple as that!

---

BTW, to make classes easier to create, we use a template like this:

```
template <typename T>
int NodeMain(int argc, char **argv, std::string const &nodeName)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, nodeName);
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::NodeHandle pnh("~");

    T a(nh, pnh);

    ros::spin();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Now you just need:

```
class MyNode
{
private:
    void callback(const ImageConstPtr& msg,const ImageConstPtr& msg2,const capygroovy::TicksConstPtr& msg3,
          message_filters::Cache<capygroovy::Ticks> &ticks_cache)
    { ... }
public:
    MyNode(ros::NodeHandle publicNodeHandle, ros::NodeHandle privateNodeHandle)
    {
        ....
        sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&callback, this, _1, _2, _3, ticks_cache));
        ....
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    NodeMain<MyNode>(argc, argv, "MyNode");
}
```

We also have a slightly more complicated template for a `nodelet`, and it means we can use `class MyNode` as either a stand-alone node or a nodelet without any code changes.

---

Originally posted by [KenYN](https://answers.ros.org/users/25651/kenyn/) with karma: 541 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I use the following code to use message filters inside a class

```
class SubscribeAndPublish
{

public:

SubscribeAndPublish():sync2(image_sub,image_sub2,500){      

image_sub.subscribe(n, "/camera/color/image_raw", 1);

image_sub2.subscribe(n, "/camera/aligned_depth_to_color/image_raw", 1);

sync2.registerCallback(boost::bind(&SubscribeAndPublish::callback,this, _1, _2));

odom_pub = n.advertise<nav_msgs::Odometry>("RGBDodom", 50);

}

private:
    ros::NodeHandle n;

    ros::Publisher odom_pub;

    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image_sub;

    message_filters::Subscriber<Image> image_sub2;

    TimeSynchronizer<Image, Image> sync2;
};
```

---

Originally posted by [arminkazim](https://answers.ros.org/users/36033/arminkazim/) with karma: 103 on 2019-11-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [berk tepebag](https://answers.ros.org/users/40401/berk-tepebag/) on 2020-03-23**:
I also had to add Node:: before callback to make it work. Otherwise throws "ISO C++ forbids taking the address of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function." error.

```
            sync.registerCallback(boost::bind(&Node::callback, this, _1, _2));
```